# How to safely parse Geo-coordinates (Latitude , Longitude) from a SharePoint Bing Maps POINT Value?

Tags: c#, regex, ssis, geocoding, string-parsing

We are using a SharePoint List to store Location information. The List uses a Bing Maps Component that lets a user editing the SharePoint List select a location on a Bing Map. Internally, the Geocordinates of the Location are stored as some kind of `Point` object.

When I query the List using the SharePoint List Adapter, I get a `String` with the Geo-coordinates as shown below (This is in the **SSIS Data Viewer**).

[image]

Here's the actual data pasted (for your reference)

```
POINT (-96.082211 41.209486)
POINT (-96.099613 41.277599)
POINT (-96.104125 41.233525)
POINT (-96.120664 41.266411)
POINT (-96.1287887 41.205003)
```

I am using C# in an SSIS Scripting Component, to extract `Latitude` and `Longitude` values, which is in between `POINT (` and `)` for each value for each row that I am processing.

Here's my code. It works.

```
public override void SourceRows_ProcessInputRow(SourceRowsBuffer Row)
{
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    try
    {
        if (!Row.Maps_IsNull)
        {
            string[] point = Row.Maps.Substring(7, Row.Maps.Length - 8).Split(' ');
            if (Double.TryParse(point[1], out latitude))
                Row.Latitude = latitude;
            if (Double.TryParse(point[0], out longitude))
                Row.Longitude = longitude;
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: log error
        Console.WriteLine( ex.Message);
        // at this point, the latitude and longitude for the row will be null.
    }
}
```

Here's the output.

[image]

#### The Question

I know my existing code works, but I want to know if there is a better, more elegant and less error-prone way of doing this. Because the hard-coded starting point for the `Substring` and the array items in the `Split` are not ideal and is prone to `IndexOutOfRangeException` etc. Of course the `Latitude` and `Longitude` will simply be empty, but I think there's a better way.

Let me know! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like the following to get the `Latitude` and `Longitude`. You'll have to modify it to get it to work with your code but it should be enough to give you the idea.

```
string input = "POINT (-96.082211 41.209486)";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"\((-?\d+.?\d+) (-?\d+.?\d+)\)");

string lat = match.Groups[1].Value;
string lon = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

The key is the regex pattern `"\((-?\d+.?\d+) (-?\d+.?\d+)\)"` which creates two matching groups for the doubles inside the parentheses of the input string.

Comment: Thanks Spencer! This works nicely and I was thinking Regex would be the solution. I created a dotNetFiddle to test it out. Works like a Boss => https://dotnetfiddle.net/0yyIBQ